# How to download a file from a private repository using curl?

Tags: c++, windows, curl, github-api, libcurl

I'm trying to download a file from a `private` GitHub repository, current code:

```
   #include <curl/curl.h>
 
   static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp) {
        size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
        auto& mem = *static_cast<std::string*>(userp);
        mem.append(static_cast<char*>(contents), realsize);
        return realsize;
    }
    
    
    
    void Download(std::string& data, char* url)
    {
        CURL* curl_handle;
        CURLcode res;
        struct curl_slist* slist{};
    
        curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
    
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        SecureZeroMemory(url, strlen(url));        

        slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Authorization: token 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");
        slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type: application/json");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
    
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 0);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);  // redirects
       
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); // only to debug
    
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
    
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
           std::cerr << "curl_easy_perform() failed: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << '\n';
    
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
        curl_global_cleanup();
    }


    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
         std::string data;
         Download(data, /* link */);
    }
```

This is what being downloaded to `data`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-color-mode="auto" data-light-theme="light" data-dark-theme="dark" data-a11y-animated-images="system">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github.githubassets.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://github.githubassets.com" crossorigin>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com">
...
```

I think the problem is setting the authorization token, i also tried:

```
slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Authorization: Bearer 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");
slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: Use 
REST API https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api

Comment: The API tells to do almost the same

Comment: No, it's not the same, you are guessing with a random code, but that link is the guideline.

Comment: This... Is not your real api token right? Or did you intend to summon @Yrll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Authorization and Accept headers like this:

```
slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Authorization: token <Your Token>");
slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+raw");
```

then call

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
```

and provide the link to the file in this form:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repository>/contents/<path>
```

Comment: When I modify the file being downloaded in the repo it takes like 10min to curl download the new data. I think its a 'problem' on github side because downloading from cmd also download old data, do you have any tips to force github update it quickly?

Comment: I don't. It works well at my place, perhaps it's temporal or local issue.

Comment: ItI can be cached, have you tried adding timestamp or counter to query string? Like https://api.github…./filename.txt?t=12345 and next time increase the value after “t”?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the line

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
```

in your code somewhere, otherwise your carefully created header list isn't used at all in the request and no authentication token is transferred at all.

Also - since you are using a GET request - the header

```
slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type: application/json");
```

doesn't make a whole lot of sense and

```
slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Authorization: Bearer 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");
```

would suffice (And I dearly hope this isn't your actual token! If it is, invalidate it quickly and generate a new one!).

Comment: I tried adding `curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);` but it continues downloading the same thing, also about the token its only an example.

Comment: @Daniel To help you any further, you'd have to specify the URL you are trying to download and the complete response your are getting. Because I don't think it is a problem with your code anymore, if you included the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER line I suggested.

Comment: @Daniel On second thought... did you try to remove the `Content-Type` header as well? This may actually confuse libcurl as to what to use - a GET or a POST request.